# How to generate Doxygen Documentation with Travis-CI

Tags: github, travis-ci, doxygen

I have a project supported in Travis-CI. I want to generate the documentation using Doxygen but Im not sure how to make it. I already have a Doxyfile in the root of the Github project. How can I do it?

Thanks in advance for your help.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know whether or not you are on a commercial plan for Travis-CI or are using it for free for a OSS project. In the later case be aware of their new pricing policy.

You didn't mention the OS for which you want to run doxygen, for some distributions an installation package is available.

To run doxygen you have to install doxygen (or build it on Travis, but this would be a bit of an overkill). After installing it you should be able to run doxygen right out of the box.

Comment: I want to use Linux. Could you specify how should I put that on my .travis.yml?

Comment: I never tried to install doxygen on Travis-CI as the purpose for the usage in our case was to build and test doxygen internally, so we needed to build doxygen itself. Due to the new pricing policy we recently moved from Travis-CI to GiHub Actions.